# How to query all distinct embedded documents in all documents

Tags: json, mongodb

For example, I want to list all registered publishers in my DB. How would I do that with this embedded document:

```
{
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher: {
              name: "O'Reilly Media",
              founded: 1980,
              location: "CA"
            }
}
```

I want to retrieve ALL DISTINCT publishers independently of its books. It would be easier if I use document reference like this:

```
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   books: [123456789, 234567890, ...]
}

{
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English"
}
```

But I don't want to do this way.

Comment: You can query to get all publishers using `db.collection_name.find({}, {publisher:1})`. For distinct publishers you can try `db.collection_name.distinct("publisher")`

Comment: I think this is what I want

Comment: But what about distinct's performance? It would check every book, even books that its publisher is already retrieved. Am I right?

Comment: Downvote without comment. :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get all the publishers regardless of books? Have you tried MongoDB Aggregation $project pipeline?

Something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0, //This line is optional
            "publisher": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
db.getCollection('yourCollectionName').aggregate([
{
   $group: {
       _id: "$publisher"
       } 
}
])
```